# Name for class with `get existing or create new` logic

Tags: oop, design-patterns, repository-pattern, factory-pattern

I have an `User` class, a repository with `find` method for finding existing user (in a storage) and a factory, which creates new user on demand.

No my question is where would I put the `getExistingOrMakeNew` method?

I guess it doesn't really fit to respository/factory classes - if so it should be isolated to a separate class. What would be the right name? Is there a known pattern for this?

Comment: This is not meant to be a criticism, merely to change your thinking a bit: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/232746/do-design-patterns-stifle-creativity

Comment: @cobaltduck - Normaly I would make an `UserManager` class to solve my problem. I've done that a few times. It all works, but `manager` is such a generic name - you can put a lot in there. So you do, and then the class grows. So I don't really see how that question you mentioned relates to mine - I'm not asking for a pattern without trying to solve things myself. I'm asking, because I want to have cleaner code.

Comment: Do you really need a factory to create a user instance?

Comment: @Bart - Yes, there are some things generated when creating new instance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just create a factory that have access to repository and can use it during creation process?